# How can i change a navbar logo img, background and links color?

Tags: preact

I have a Preact project and i want to change the navbar backgroundcolor, the img src and the links color, when I start scrolling down. How can i do that? Im new in Preact and a bit confusing that i just name a class like class={style.classname}.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **scroll** event, you will need to register on `window` object which is the concern outside of your component. So if using class-based component, you can use appropriate callback handler or use `useEffect` hook to register external event when using Functional Component.

For example, when using functional component, you can:

```
import { h } from 'preact';
import { useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';

function function addEvent(node, eventName, callback) {

  node.addEventListener(eventName, callback);

  // Note the use of de-registration/unsubscribe function
  return () => node.removeEventListener(eventName, callback);
}


export function AppComp(props) {

  // The dependency array is empty since it doesn't depend on anything.
  useEffect(() => {
    const deregister = addEvent(window, 'scroll', () => {
      // Your logic on scroll.
    });

    // Remove the event subscription when component is destroyed
    return () => deregister();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Hello</div>
  );
}
```

Note the use of `addEvent` function. It returns a de-registration function which can be used remove the attached event, typically, when component is destroyed ensuring no memory leaks or unwanted state.